# PHP - Replace Prolog Tag in XML stored in Variable

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl

I am using PHP to access a web service which returns data for a single user in XML format and stores this in a variable named `$results_users_xml` (including the prolog tag).

`$results_users_xml` contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<User xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dmu="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/user-metadata" username="ppurfiel" dmu:userId="1600263"> 
    <FirstName>Patrick</FirstName> 
    <LastName>Purfield</LastName> 
    <Email>ppurfiel@msudenver.edu</Email> 
    <LocalAuthentication/> 
    <dmu:Schemas xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="/login/service/v4/UserSchema/USERNAME:ppurfiel"/> 
    <dmr:Roles xmlns:dmr="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/role-metadata" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="/login/service/v4/UserRole/USERNAME:ppurfiel"/> 
</User>
```

From this XML string I have stored the existing Prolog tag like this:
`$orig_xml_tag = "&lt;?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?&gt;";`

I've defined a variable containing the desired Prolog tag:
`$xsl_tag = "&lt;?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"curl_test.xsl\"?&gt;";`

In the variable containing the XML data (`$results_users_xml`) I'd like to replace the original Prolog tag (`$orig_xml_tag`) with the desired Prolog tag (`$xsl_tag`). The result would be stored in a new variable.

I have been trying different PHP functions, including `str_replace()` and `substr_replace()` but in each case the original Prolog does not get replace with desired Prolog. For example I have tried:

```
echo str_replace($orig_xml_tag, $xsl_tag, $results_users_xml);

echo substr_replace($orig_xml_tag, $xsl_tag, 0);
```

But in each case the desired substitution does not work and the original XML value (`$results_users_xml`) remains unchanged.

Many thanks for any and all help,
Patrick

Comment: Welcome to SO! Assign the result of `str_replace(..)` back to `$results_users_xml`?

Comment: I was able to get the desired result by using substr() to substring out the portion of the string that I want to keep (ie excluding the XML prolog tag).  Then I used concatenate to attach the new tag to the from of the string.   Many Thanks!